# Silverlight - Get a point on BezierSegment

Tags: silverlight, geometry, bezier

I am using the `Path` class and a `BezierSegment` in my Silverlight application.
I am drawing different arches and lines using it.

What I'd like to do is get the middle of the my arch / line.
I noticed that the `BezierSegment` doesn't go through the second point, but merely comes near to it. 
How can I get the real curve point (its coordinates) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BezierSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.beziersegment%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class uses cubic Bézier curves, and [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) gives the equation of such curves.  You can take this equation and put *t* = 0.5 into it to get a point somewhere on the curve.

Note that the point at *t* = 0.5 isn't guaranteed to be exactly half-way along the curve from the start to the end.  Getting the exact midpoint of the curve is more complicated, and if you really need that, you'll be best off asking how to calculate it at https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If your curves are symmetric, the midpoint is at (start + Point3 + 3 * Point1 + 3 * Point2) / 8.